# Pandas y numpy en visual studio code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, anaconda

No se como hacer que estos módulos funcionen en este programa, lo importé de la siguiente manera:
`import pandas as pd
import numpy as np`

Y dice que no hay modulos llamados asi, los instalé por anaconda, y tal vez toque configurar al visual studio para que los reconozca, pero si es así no se como hacerlo...

Answer (score 1):

Si pandas te esta funcionando correctamente en la terminal, lo mas probable es que en el environment en que te encuentres no es el correcto.

Para cambiarlo en VSCODE, puedes seleccionar el environment (donde tenga pandas instalado) en la parte inferior izquierda como puedes ver en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]